# Add stopover to waypoints

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having trouble adding stopover points to my google maps route. This is my calcRoute function below. Basically I have an array of latlng objects called waypts and all the points between waypts[0] and waypts[waypts.length-1] should be stopover points. I know I just need to loop through those points and make a stopover with something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var directionsDisplay;
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      var map;
      var phpway = <?php echo json_encode($phpway); ?>;
      var waypts = [];

      for(var i = 0; i < phpway.length; i+=2){
        waypts.push(new google.maps.LatLng(phpway[i], phpway[i+1])); 
      }

      function initialize() {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 6,
          center: chicago
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      }

      function calcRoute() {
        var start = waypts[0];
        var end = waypts[waypts.length-1];
        var mywaypts = [];
        for (var i = 1; i < waypts.length-1; i++) {

            mywaypts.push({
                location:waypts[i],
                stopover:true});

        }

        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            waypoints: mywaypts,
            optimizeWaypoints: true,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            var route = response.routes[0];

          }
        });
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not include your start/end points in your waypoints array, and just pass your `waypts` array in your request this way:

```
var request = {
    origin : start,
    destination : end,
    waypoints: waypts,
    travelMode : google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};
```

See doc: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions?hl=FR#Waypoints

Comment: Can you look why it doesn't work now. I've used your example from google maps and made a new array that holds all the middle points. I have edited my question above and that's how it looks now.

Comment: Could you add a sample of your phpway value?

Comment: ["37.78772866390086", "-122.468891143798", "37.78474404781106", "-122.397308349609", "37.76886929179321", "-122.451210021972"] is what is output by using console.log(phpway)

Comment: It is working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/2ekhLk4e/ you got 3 points, your start, your end, and a stopover